# Pyside QComboBox Incorrect Argument Error when using Partial

Tags: python, pyside

Getting a TypeError wrong argument amounts called when i use partial to dynamically connect the currentIndexChanged Signal. Same function call works fine with other widgets like QPushBUttons.

Tried switching from Partial to Lambda, but Lambda will not pass back the correct information since widgets are being dynamically created.

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages")
from PySide import QtGui
from   functools import *


class test(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # init window settings
        self.windowName = 'test'
        self.windowWidth  = 50
        self.windowHeight = 400
        self.setWindowTitle(self.windowName)
        self.setObjectName (self.windowName)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,200,150)
        self.resize(self.windowWidth,self.windowHeight)
        main = self.mainLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(main)

    def mainLayout(self):
        wid = QtGui.QWidget()
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(wid)
        but = self.buttons()
        lay.addWidget(but)
        return wid

    def buttons(self):
        wid = QtGui.QWidget()
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(wid)

        #ComboBox Error: buttonCall() takes exactly 7 arguments (8 given)
        for i in range(2):
            but = QtGui.QComboBox()
            for x in range(2):
                but.addItem(str(x))
            but.currentIndexChanged.connect(partial(self.buttonCall,'test','a','b','c','d',but))
            lay.addWidget(but)

        #PushButton works Fine with same function call
        for i in range(2):
            but2 = QtGui.QPushButton(str(i))
            but2.pressed.connect(partial(self.buttonCall,'test','a','b','c','d',but2))
            lay.addWidget(but2)

        #Lambda wont give error but is assing the incorrect information
        for i in range(2):
            but3 = QtGui.QComboBox()
            for x in range(2):
                but3.addItem(str(x))
            but3.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda:self.buttonCall('test','a','b','c','d',but))
            lay.addWidget(but3)

        return wid


    def buttonCall(self,asset,a,b,c,d,button):
        print asset
        print a
        print b
        print c
        print d
        print button

app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

a = test()
a.show()
```

changing combo box will give back error : Error: buttonCall() takes exactly 7 arguments (8 given)

Answer (score 0):

By QComboBox.currentIndexChanged signal the new item's index is sent to the connected function. So clicking on a item, if the item is different from the current item, you'll call self.buttonCall(self,'test','a','b','c','d',but, N) where N is the index of the clicked item

**To solve in Python2**, use but.currentIndexChanged.connect(partial(self.buttonCall,'test','a','b','c','d',but))

and add a dummy argument to buttonCall method

```
def buttonCall(self,asset,a,b,c,d,but,dummy=None):
    print asset
    print a
    print b
    print c
    print d
    print but
    print dummy, type(dummy) #To test
```

The test result by Python27+PySide is displayed below

```
test
a
b
c
d
<PySide.QtGui.QComboBox object at 0x03D7D530>
1 <type 'int'>
test
a
b
c
d
<PySide.QtGui.QComboBox object at 0x03D7D558>
1 <type 'int'>
```

In Python3 'partial' statement is no longer used so you can add a bridge method to send the ComboBox Id to buttonCall

Here it is the entire code for **Python3/PySide2 (or PyQy5)**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages")
from PySide2 import QtGui,QtWidgets

class test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # init window settings
        self.windowName = 'test'
        self.windowWidth  = 50
        self.windowHeight = 400
        self.setWindowTitle(self.windowName)
        self.setObjectName (self.windowName)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,200,150)
        self.resize(self.windowWidth,self.windowHeight)
        main = self.mainLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(main)

    def mainLayout(self):
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(wid)
        but = self.buttons()
        lay.addWidget(but)
        return wid

    def buttons(self):
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(wid)

        for i in range(2):
            but2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(str(i))

            def bridge(but=but2):                               #add this bridge
                self.buttonCall('test','a','b','c','d',but)     #method

            but2.pressed.connect(bridge)
            lay.addWidget(but2)

        for i in range(2):
            but3 = QtWidgets.QComboBox()

            def bridge(newindex, but=but3):                           #add this bridge
                self.buttonCall('test','a','b','c','d',but,newindex)  #method

            for x in range(2):
                but3.addItem(str(x))
                but3.index=x
            lay.addWidget(but3)
            but3.currentIndexChanged.connect(bridge)

        return wid

    def buttonCall(self,asset,a,b,c,d,button,dummy=None):
        print (asset)
        print (a)
        print (b)
        print (c)
        print (d)
        print (button)
        print (dummy, type(dummy))

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([''])

a = test()
a.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The test result by Python38+PySide2 is displayed below

```
test
a
b
c
d
<PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox object at 0x0456EA90>
1 <class 'int'>
test
a
b
c
d
<PySide2.QtWidgets.QComboBox object at 0x0456EB20>
1 <class 'int'>
```